# $f, g$ are continuous functions on $[0,1] $ with $f(0)=f(1)=0;g(0)=g(1)=1$ and $f(1/2)>g(1/2)$, number of pts s.t. $f(t) =g(t) $

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Given $f, g$ are continuous functions on $[0,1] $ such that $f(0)=f(1)=0;g(0)=g(1)=1$ and $f(1/2)>g(1/2)$.Which of the following statements are true?
(a) There is no $t\in[0,1]$ such that $f(t) =g(t) $
(b) there is exactly one $t\in[0,1]$ such that $f(t) =g(t) $
(c) There are at least two $t\in [0,1] $ such that $f(t) =g(t) $
(d) There are always infinitely many $t\in [0,1] $ such that $f(t) =g(t)$
$\color{blue}{\bf{Try:} }$
Choosing $f(x) =|\sin\left(\pi x\right)| $ and $g(x) =|\cos\left(\pi x\right)|$  from the graph we can see there are two points with $f(t) =g(t) $. But how to justify $\color{red} {exactly} $ two such points exist (if my thinking is right). I also want to know if without taking examples there is a way to solve the problem directly.

.

Comment: You cannot justify that there are exactly 2 such points. But there are atleast 2 such points, by intermediate value theorem.

Comment: In fact, your example already answers your question: the only answer that isn't contradicted is (b)

Comment: @QC_QAOA I think my example contradict (b). Cause (b) says exactly one point but the example says two such points. So contradicted. Isn't it?

Comment: @Math_Learner My bad, for some reason I thought the "at least $2$ points answer was (b) not (c).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider $f(t) - g(t)$. This is less than 0 at $t=0$, and more than 0 at $t=\frac{1}{2}$. Therefore there must be one point for $t\in(0,\frac{1}{2})$ where $f(t) - g(t)=0$ by the [intermediate value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem), at such a t, $f(t) = g(t)$.

Similarly, there exists a point for $t\in(\frac{1}{2},1)$where $f(t) - g(t)=0$ as $f(\frac{1}{2}) - g(\frac{1}{2})>0$ and $f(1) - g(1)<0$

Finally, we cannot say there are exactly two because the given conditions do not exclude f(t) = g(t) for an entire interval between $(0,\frac{1}{2})$ or $(\frac{1}{2},1)$

Comment: I don't understand how $f(t) =g(t) $ for an entire interval $(0,1/2)$ or $(1/2,1)$ is possible? Please describe me.

Comment: I'll define one example where the functions overlap in some interval $I \subset (0,\frac{1}{2})$ for illustration: $f(t) = \begin{cases}3t&t\in[0,\frac{1}{6}]\\\frac{1}{2} & t\in (\frac{1}{6},\frac{1}{3}]\\ \frac{1}{2} + 3(t-\frac{1}{3}) & t\in (\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{2}]\\ 1-2(t-\frac{1}{2}) & t \in (\frac{1}{2},1] \end{cases}$ and $g(t) = \begin{cases}1-3t&t\in[0,\frac{1}{6}]\\\frac{1}{2} & t\in (\frac{1}{6},\frac{1}{3}]\\ \frac{1}{2} - 3(t-\frac{1}{3}) & t\in (\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{2}]\\ 2(t-\frac{1}{2})& t\in (\frac{1}{2},1] \end{cases}$. These coincide between $[\frac{1}{6},\frac{1}{3}]$.

Comment: Thanks for this huge effort. (+2).

Answer (score 2):

It follows from the intermediate value theorem that the equation $f(t)=g(t)$ have a solution on $\left(0,\frac12\right)$ and also a solution on $\left(\frac12,0\right)$. So, (a) and (b) are false, and (c) is true. But (d) is false too, as your example shows.

Comment: Thanks.. I accept Rahul Madhaban's answer because he commented first. Thanks for your effort (+1).